# Doesn't have copy constructor? Not trying to copy

Tags: c#, c++-cli

C# code fragment:

```
public class XmlConfig : IDisposable
{
  static public XmlConfig LoadedCfgx { get { return loaded; } }
}
public class ConfigRetainerRingPresenter
{
  public ConfigRetainerRingPresenter(XmlConfig config)
  {
  }
}
```

C++/CLI code fragment:

```
ConfigRetainerRingPresenter g(XmlConfig::LoadedCfgx);
ConfigRetainerRingPresenter ^h = gcnew ConfigRetainerRingPresenter (XmlConfig::LoadedCfgx);
```

Compiler errors:

```
1>h:\configinterop.cpp(58): error C3673: 'Config::ConfigRetainerRingPresenter' : class does not have a copy-constructor
1>h:\configinterop.cpp(59): error C3673: 'Config::ConfigRetainerRingPresenter' : class does not have a copy-constructor
```

Can somebody explain to me why the program is expecting a copy constructor?

EDIT: Added a default constructor to ConfigRetainerRingPresenter() and the error message went away.  I'm not using the default constructor.  Can anybody explain?

```
public ConfigRetainerRingPresenter() { }
```

Comment: I feared this might happen.  Not clear how to reduce the difference.  Nothing complicated going on in the C# classes, but all the methods are used by other C# stuff so I can't exactly disable them and still compile that DLL.

Comment: You've shown an error message on lines 58 and 59. Are those the declarations of `g` and `h` that you've shown?

Comment: Yes, those are the declarations and their line numbers.